# How to find Fortran error message when "R Session Aborted" running compiled code?

Tags: r, fortran, rstudio, r-package

I am developing an R package with compiled Fortran code ([rsofun](https://github.com/stineb/rsofun)). It successfully compiles and the package builds. However, I get a runtime crash when calling the function that wraps the Fortran code. RStudio raises the following:

*R Session Aborted. R encountered a fatal error. The session was terminated.*

Unfortunately, this doesn't display the Fortran error that has caused the crash. How can I find the Fortran error message?

To reproduce the crash, run the vignette `vignettes/example_pmodel.Rmd` in [rsofun](https://github.com/stineb/rsofun).

This is odd also because it crashes on one of my machines, but not on the other. On the machine where it crashes, I have (i.a.) the following specified in the Makeconf file:

```
FC = gfortran -mmacosx-version-min=10.13
FCFLAGS = -Wall -g -O2 $(LTO)
FCLIBS_XTRA = 
FFLAGS = -Wall -g -O2 $(LTO)
FLIBS =  -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15/6.1.0 -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm
ALL_FFLAGS =  $(PKG_FFLAGS) $(FPICFLAGS) $(SHLIB_FFLAGS) $(FFLAGS)
...
```

And `gfortran` points to:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 username  admin  34 May 14  2020 /usr/local/bin/gfortran -> ../Cellar/gcc/9.3.0_1/bin/gfortran
```

Session Info:

```
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.7

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
```

**UPDATE**

Instead of running an RMarkdown in RStudio, I call the problematic function in a Bash shell with `Rscript` (script added to git repo):

```sh
Rscript Rscripts/example_pmodel.R
```

... and get the following error:

```
 *** caught segfault ***
address 0xa, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: run_pmodel_f_bysite(df_drivers$sitename[1], df_drivers$params_siml[[1]],     df_drivers$siteinfo[[1]], df_drivers$forcing[[1]], df_drivers$df_soiltexture[[1]],     params_modl = params_modl, makecheck = TRUE)
An irrecoverable exception occurred. R is aborting now ...
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Still, I don't know how to fix that. Maybe [this issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/322) provides a lead? ("mismatch between currently installed shared libraries and the libraries that were built to install R or packages.").

How can I make sure it's all using the right libraries? I tried to re-install packages (dependencies of the package built here) from source. But no success...

Comment: Have you tried running outside of RStudio?  Open a Terminal, and run `Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('vignettes/example_pmodel.Rmd')"` in the main directory of the project.  I don't know if you'll get more info, but you might.

Comment: When I do that I get `Error in library(ingestr) : there is no package called 'ingestr'`, presumably not the same crash as you're getting.

Comment: Thanks for the lead! 
I added `Rscripts/example_pmodel.R` to the git repo to reproduce it as an R script. I now get the following error:

```r
 *** caught segfault ***
address 0xa, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: run_pmodel_f_bysite(df_drivers$sitename[1], df_drivers$params_siml[[1]],     df_drivers$siteinfo[[1]], df_drivers$forcing[[1]], df_drivers$df_soiltexture[[1]],     params_modl = params_modl, makecheck = TRUE)
An irrecoverable exception occurred. R is aborting now ...
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Comment: I don't see that file there, but I created it myself.  The next step would normally be to run `R` under a debugger, e.g. `R -d lldb` or `R -d gdb` and source the script from there.